# Gmail not rendering email with html breaks properly when sent from Django

Tags: html, django, gmail, hotmail

I'm currently using Django to send an email to a user who has forgotten their password. All other email clients render the email properly with the breaks. However Gmail doesn't seem to care about the html and it squishes all the text together.

**Here's what the email looks when rendered in hotmail:**

Hello Bob,

You are receiving this email because you have (or someone pretending to be you has) requested a new password to be sent for your account. If you did not request this email then you can let us know at support@mailapp.com.

To reset your password, enter the temporary password below to login.

TEMPORARY PASSWORD: seBDTZK4cc

Once you are logged in, you can change your password in the "Edit Profile" option under "Account" in Settings.

-The Mail App Team

**However in gmail, it looks like this!:**

Hello Bob,You are receiving this email because you have (or someone pretending to be you has) requested a new password to be sent for your account. If you did not request this email then you can let us know at support@mailapp.com.To reset your password, enter the temporary password below to login.TEMPORARY PASSWORD: seBDTZK4ccOnce you are logged in, you can change your password in the "Edit Profile" option under "Account" in Settings.-The Mail App Team

This is confusing users who have a gmail account because the temporary password is being combined with the next sentence!

**Here is the code from Django that I am using to send the emails:**

```
def resetpassword(request): 
    data = json.loads(request.raw_post_data) 
    requestusername = data['username'] 
    requestemail = data['email'] 
    if User.objects.filter(username = requestusername).exists():
        user_who_forgot_password = User.objects.get(username = requestusername) 
        if user_who_forgot_password.email == requestemail: 

            password = User.objects.make_random_password() 
            user_who_forgot_password.set_password(password) 
            user_who_forgot_password.save()
            email = EmailMessage('Password Reset On Mail App', 'Hello %s,</br></br>You are receiving this email because you have (or someone pretending to be you has) requested a new password to be sent for your account. If you did not request this email then you can let us know at support@mailapp.com.</br></br>To reset your password, enter the temporary password below to login.</br></br><b>TEMPORARY PASSWORD:</b> %s</br></br>Once you are logged in, you can change your password in the "Edit Profile" option under "Account" in Settings.</br></br>-The MailApp Team' % (user_who_forgot_password.username, password), to = ['{email}'.format(email=requestemail,)]) 
            email.content_subtype = "html" 
            email.send() 
            print 'Password Email Sent' 
            return HttpResponse("Success") 
        else: 
            return HttpResponse("No email found") 
    else: 
        return HttpResponse("No username found")
```

How can I fix it so that it can be rendered in Gmail in such a way that it is displayed properly like Hotmail?

Comment: You have an XSS hole; you need to HTML-escape the username & password.

Answer (score 16):

`</br>` is invalid HTML.

You should write `<br>` (with not closing tag), or the XML-style `<br />` (a self-closing tag)

Comment: could you give me a more detailed answer using the code I gave so that I may upvote your answer and accept it! :)

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this? 'Hello %s,<br><br>You are receiving this email because you have (or someone pretending to be you has) requested a new password to be sent for your account. If you did not request this email then you can let us know at support@mailapp.com.<br><br>To reset your password, enter the temporary password below to login.<br><br><b>TEMPORARY PASSWORD:<b> %s<br><br>Once you are logged in, you can change your password in the "Edit Profile" option under "Account" in Settings.<br><br>-The MailApp Team' ?